# Two master instances on same database

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, failover

I want to use Postgresql in Windows Server 2012 R2 for one our project where it can be 24/7 uptime.

I would like to ask the community if I can have 2 master instances in 2 different servers A&B and they will 'work' on the same DB located in a shared file storage in lan. Always one master instance on server A will be online and when it goes offline for some reason (I suppose) a powershell script will recognize that the postgresql service stopped and will start the service in server B. The same script will continuous check that only one service in servers A & B is working to avoid conflicts.

I'd like to ask if this is possible or a better approach for my configuration.
(I can't use replication because when server A shuts down the server B is in read-only mode thing that I don't want)

Answer (score 3):

If you manage to start two instances of PostgreSQL on the same data directory, serious data corruption *will happen*.

Normally there is a `postmaster.pid` file that prevents that, but a PostgreSQL server process on a different machine that accesses the same file system will happily unlink that after spewing some log messages, thinking it was left behind from a crash.

So you are really walking on thin ice with a solution like that.

One other issue that you didn't think of is that script that is supposed to check if the server is still running. What if that script fails, because for example the network connection between the two servers is down, but the server is still up an running happily? Such a “split brain” scenario will cause data corruption with your setup.

Another word of caution: since you seem to be using Windows (Powershell?), you probably envision a CIFS file system when you are talking of shared storage. A Windows “network share” is *not* a reliable file system — last time I checked, it did not honor [`_commit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685.aspx).

Creating a reliable failover cluster is harder than you think, and I'd recommend that you check existing solutions before you try to roll your own.

Comment: First thanks for the response. You are right and that's why i am asking here, but i didn't manage to find an existing solution working in windows server. All the tools are for linux systems. The only solution i found as i referred above is with wal archiving, a senario where the slave server is always on read-only mode when master is down and can't work with our app. Do you have any other configuration in mind to suggest in windows enviroment?

Comment: I don't do Windows... Did you look at the [PostgreSQL Wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Clustering) that lists clustering solutions? Perhaps [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Shared_Storage) is interesting as well.

Comment: Yes, this senario i am describing above but i am not sure if it will operate well and i wanted a second opinion!

Comment: I would *not* use Windows for anything advaced like that.